# Mismatch between HTTP 'charset' and XML 'encoding'

Tags: xml, http, encoding, character-encoding

I have encountered a web service that is returning an HTTP `Content-Type` header with a **UTF-8** `charset`:

```
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
```

...and an XML declaration `encoding` attribute whose value is **ISO-8859-1** (aka, **latin1**):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no" ?>
```

When I attempt to display a response from this web service in Firefox, it displays **XML Parsing Error: not well-formed** when it encounters an **á** ([small letter a with acute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81)).

The fact that Firefox issues this parsing error doesn't come as a surprise to me. I want to say that an XML encoding that is not equivalent to the HTTP character set is **never** correct. Am I right? Should such a situation *always* be considered a web server configuration problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problem

You have `test/xml` and `UTF-8` charset. In that case, section 8.1 "Text/xml with UTF-8 Charset" of [RFC 3023](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3023) applies.

> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>
> This is the recommended charset value for use with text/xml.  Since the charset parameter is provided, MIME and XML processors MUST treat the enclosed entity as UTF-8 encoded.

Unfortunately this only defines the case where the XML encoding is also `utf-8`, which you don't have here.

However, there is one more section, 8.20 "Inconsistent Example: Text/xml with UTF-8 Charset", which exactly mentions the case you have:

> Content-type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
>
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
>
> Since the charset parameter is provided in the Content-Type header, MIME and XML processors MUST treat the enclosed entity as UTF-8 encoded.  That is, the "iso-8859-1" encoding MUST be ignored.

Now, your document probably (you should verify with a hex editor) contains á in ISO-8859-1 form, which is `0xE1` (hex). Since the ISO Encoding is ignored and UTF-8 applies, this should be `0xC3 0xA1` instead.

In UTF-8, `0xE1` is not a character itself. Instead, it is the beginning of a 3 byte character sequence covering the Unicode range U+1000 to U+1FFF. To know what it would decode to, we would need to know the next 2 bytes that follow the á. It is quite likely that it is followed a "normal" character from the ASCII set. This would be an invalid character, since the 2 bytes that follow the `0xE1` must be `0x80` or higher - thus an encoding error occurs.

### Your questions

> I want to say that an XML encoding that is not equivalent to the HTTP character set is never correct. Am I right?

Well, it's at least not recommended and you'll need to know RFC 3023 in detail in order to know what happens in such a case. It's much easier if the content type and encoding match.

> Should such a situation always be considered a web server configuration problem?

No. It could also be an implementation issue, e.g. the programmer has defined the content type and encoding in the application and you can't do much against it in the webserver configuration.

Comment: RFC 3023 Section 8.20 "Inconsistent Example: Text/xml with UTF-8 Charset" does indeed precisely address the situation that I encountered. Regarding my question "Should such a situation always be considered a web server configuration problem?" From the perspective of the *client*, I think it would be fair to say that it *is* a web server (or web service) configuration problem. That is, there is nothing that is "reasonable" that the client itself can do to fix the problem. Instead, whoever (server admin and/or developer)  is responsible for the web site in question should fix the problem, yes?

Comment: @DavidRR: yes, from a client's perspective, you can't do much about it. The IT admin may not be able to configure something or, if not, the developer must fix it.

Comment: the client can be a bit smart and determine if it is not utf8 according to the first 8bit sequence - if it is not valid utf8. But that wont be rfc compliant but an interoperability hack - but might be required if you want to talk to many unknown endpoints. (catch EncodingExceptin and retry with declaration charset and finally latin1)